# System Configuration multi date selection Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, system-config, system-configuration, datepicker

I need to add option to select multiple dates in system configure. I can add single date input field in system configure. but I doesn't have any idea about to add multi date picker in system configure.

> **system.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="carriers" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="320" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="customshippingmethod" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="900" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Custom Shipping Method</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="from_date" translate="label" type="date" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                  showInStore="1">
                    <label>From</label>
                    <!-- Here we pass class where we create date picker-->
                    <frontend_model>Vendor\ModuleName\Block\DatePicker</frontend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> Vendor\ModuleName\Block\**DatePicker** File

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;

class DatePicker extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
   public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
   {
       $element->setDateFormat(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
       $element->setTimeFormat('HH:mm:ss'); //set date and time as per your need
       $element->setShowsTime(true);
       return parent::render($element);
   }
}
```

see below Image to understand exactly what I have to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I share that solution with community I hope this one is helped to you.

> system.xml file

```
<field id="exclude_days" translate="label" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Exclude Days</label>
    <frontend_model>Vendor\ModuleName\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\ExcludeDaysMultipleFields</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Config\Backend\ExcludeDaysMultipleFields</backend_model>
</field>
```

> **ExcludeDaysMultipleFields** fronend Model created at `Vendor\ModuleName\Block\System\Config\Form\Field` path

```
<?php
 
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
 
class ExcludeDaysMultipleFields extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('date', ['label' => __('Date'), 'class' => 'js-date-excluded-datepicker']);
        $this->addColumn('content', ['label' => __('content'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);        
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add Date');

        parent::_prepareToRender();
    }


    /**
     * Prepare existing row data object
     * Convert backend date format "2022-01-12" to front format "12/01/2022"
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    protected function _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $key = 'date';
        if (!isset($row[$key])) return;
        $rowId = $row['_id'];
        try {
            $sourceDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row[$key]);
            $renderedDate = $sourceDate->format('d/m/Y');
            $row[$key] = $renderedDate;
            $columnValues = $row['column_values'];
            $columnValues[$this->_getCellInputElementId($rowId, $key)] = $renderedDate;
            $row['column_values'] = $columnValues;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Just skipping error values
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the grid and scripts contents
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $html = parent::_getElementHtml($element);
 
        $script = <<< JS
            <script type="text/javascript">
                // Bind click to "Add" buttons and bind datepicker to added date fields
                require(["jquery", "jquery/ui"], function (jq) {
                    jq(function(){
                        function bindDatePicker() {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                jq(".js-date-excluded-datepicker").datepicker( { dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" } );
                            }, 50);
                        }
                        bindDatePicker();
                        jq("button.action-add").on("click", function(e) {
                            bindDatePicker();
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        JS;
        
        $html .= $script;
        return $html;
    }
}
```

> **ExcludeDaysMultipleFields** backend model created at `Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Config\Backend` path

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Config\Backend;

use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value as ConfigValue;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

class ExcludeDaysMultipleFields extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized
{
    /**
     * Json Serializer
     *
     * @var SerializerInterface
     */
    protected $serializer;

    /**
     * ShippingMethods constructor
     *
     * @param SerializerInterface $serializer
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $config
     * @param TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param AbstractResource|null $resource
     * @param AbstractDb|null $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        AbstractResource $resource = null,
        AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * On save convert front value format like "12/01/2018" to backend format "2018-01-12"
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $value = [];
        $values = $this->getValue();
        foreach ((array)$values as $key => $data) {
            if ($key == '__empty') continue;
            if (!isset($data['date'])) continue;
            try {
                $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data['date']);
                $value[$key] = [
                    'date' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
                    'content' => $data['content'],
                ];
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // Just skipping error values
            }
        }
        $encodedValue = $this->serializer->serialize($value);
        $this->setValue($encodedValue);
        return parent::beforeSave();
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: output image]

Comment: see for reference https://www.magentoexpertise.in/magento-2-create-multiple-fields-in-the-system-configuration-programmatically/

Answer (score 1):

Add in your system.xml

```
<field id="dynamic_field_holidays" translate="label" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
               <label>Holidays/Exclude Days/Blackout Days</label> 
     
     <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Config\Backend\Datepicker</backend_model>
            <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Datepicker</frontend_model>
</field>
```

Create Datepicker.php file at Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Config\Backend

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Config\Backend;

use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value as ConfigValue;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

class Datepicker extends ConfigValue
{

    protected $serializer;

    public function __construct(
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        AbstractResource $resource = null,
        AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        if (isset($value['__empty'])) {
            unset($value['__empty']);
        }
        $encodedValue = $this->serializer->serialize($value);
        $this->setValue($encodedValue);
    }

    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        if ($value) {
            $decodedValue = $this->serializer->unserialize($value);
            $this->setValue($decodedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Create Datepicker.php file at Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Datepicker extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    private $holidaysRenderer;
    private $dateRenderer;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {

        $this->addColumn(
            'select_date',
            [
                'label' => __('Date'),
                'id' => 'select_date',
                'class' => 'daterecuring',
                'style' => 'width:200px'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'date_title',
            [
                'label' => __('Content'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'style' => 'width:300px',
            ]
        );

        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('MoreAdd');
    }

    protected function _prepareArrayRow(DataObject $row): void
    {
        $options = [];
        $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $html = parent::_getElementHtml($element);

        $script = '<script type="text/javascript">
                require(["jquery", "jquery/ui", "mage/calendar"], function (jq) {
                    jq(function(){
                        function bindDatePicker() {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                jq(".daterecuring").datepicker( { dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" } );
                            }, 50);
                        }
                        bindDatePicker();
                        jq("button.action-add").on("click", function(e) {
                            bindDatePicker();
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>';
        $html .= $script;
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solution. your solution is also worked. you answer & my answer almost same. just difference is using my answer it save date in standard `Y-m-d` format. & using your answer it save the date in `d/m/Y` format.